# Select all record from tags table with a virtual column that contain the match from a pivot table

Tags: mysql, pivot-table

I am trying to:

Select all tags (from tags table)

with a virtual column named selected

that contains a boolean value (es. 0 || 1)

that defines if the tag_id is associated with the given image_id

(Es. image_id = 1)

The relational dataset it's preset in a pivot table called image_tag

**Structure and data:**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `images` (
  `id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `title` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;

INSERT INTO `images` (`id`, `title`) VALUES
(1, 'Image 1'),
(2, 'Image 2');

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tags` (
  `id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `tags_name_unique` (`name`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;

INSERT INTO `tags` (`id`, `name`) VALUES
(1, 'Tag A'),
(2, 'Tag B'),
(3, 'Tag C'),
(4, 'Tag D');

/* Pivot table */
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `image_tag` (
  `image_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `tag_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`image_id`,`tag_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;

INSERT INTO `image_tag` (`image_id`, `tag_id`) VALUES
(1, 1),
(1, 2),
(2, 1),
(2, 3);

SELECT * FROM images;
/*
+----+---------+
| id | title   |
+----+---------+
|  1 | Image 1 |
|  2 | Image 2 |
+----+---------+
*/

SELECT * FROM tags;
/*
+----+-------+
| id | name  |
+----+-------+
|  1 | Tag A |
|  2 | Tag B |
|  3 | Tag C |
|  4 | Tag D |
+----+-------+
*/

SELECT * FROM image_tag;
/*
+----------+--------+
| image_id | tag_id |
+----------+--------+
|        1 |      1 |
|        1 |      2 |
|        2 |      1 |
|        2 |      3 |
+----------+--------+
*/
```

**The result that I'm looking for:**

```
/*
+----+-------+----------+
| id | tag   | selected |
+----+-------+----------+
|  1 | Tag A | 1        |
|  2 | Tag B | 1        |
|  3 | Tag C | 0        |
|  4 | Tag D | 0        |
+----+-------+----------+
*/
```

Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do a left join between the `tags` and `image_tags` tables, and then use a `CASE` expression which checks the matching count.  If the matching count be zero, then report zero for the `selected` column, otherwise report 1.

```
SELECT
    t1.id,
    t1.name AS tag,
    CASE WHEN COUNT(t2.tag_id) = 0 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS selected
FROM tags t1
LEFT JOIN image_tag t2
    ON t1.id = t2.tag_id AND
       t2.image_id = 1
GROUP BY
    t1.id,
    t1.name
ORDER BY
    t1.id;
```

Note: My original answer returned tags as matched against any image.  Since then, the OP let me know that the requirement is for tags matching to a particular image.  The above query and demo reflect this, but not the screen capture.

[image]


### Demo

Comment: I'm confuse by the result, Tag C (id 3 in `tags` table ) is not related in image_tag  with image_id = 1
therefore it should return selected = 0 as in my sample.

Comment: @F0Dev I neglected to add a `WHERE` condition in my answer.  Just add `WHERE t2.image_id = 1` to my answer to get the result you want.

Comment: Thanks, I'm pretty sure that I'm not explain well the purpose;
The purpose is to have the complete list (all) of the tags, and in it, a column that show if the tag is or is not selected / assigned to a specific image_id (es. = 1)
if I introduce your suggested WHERE t2.image_id = 1 the result is not the complete tags list as my example.

Comment: @F0Dev Sorry for the confusion, it should work now.  Move the check on `image_id` to the `ON` clause of the left join.